# adb shell returning unusual characters in output

Tags: shell, adb

When I used the backspace key or left key ... in adb shell command , the dosbox shows the strange string , for example : I typed the words "busybox" and pressed backspace key , the dosbox shows as follow

```
# busybox←[0G# busybo←[0K←[0G←[8C
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Please help me, thank you!!

Comment: Those are ["ansi control characters"](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php).  They hearken back to the day of VT100 serial terminals :)

Comment: Any reasonable terminal emulator will support them. The one that comes with current versions of cygwin, for instance.

Comment: ...that said, I'm not sure this is a software development question as such -- you're not writing code, or using tools exclusively of use to those who are.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to tell the remote system not to send any control characters, run the following on the remote system:

```
export TERM=dumb
```

Alternately, use a competent terminal emulator (which Microsoft, sadly, does not provide).

Comment: Have you tried using a terminal emulator? https://mintty.github.io/, for instance -- aka the "Cygwin Terminal" or "Git Bash Terminal"

Comment: I just tried `ConEmu`, and it worked good there - Backspace functions normally.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) for your terminal windows.

Enable the "Inject ConEmuHk.dll into all processes started in ConEmu tabs" setting in Settings -> General. It's on by default so this is just a safety check.